# How to set up a connection to a database for a program that will be distributed

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have a program that currently points to a database on my local drive.  I will be placing the dataset on a network drive on a server and then distributing the program to other compters.  How am I to set up a connection that will work on other compuers(where the network drive letter may be different)?  I have tried seting this up through the App.Config file as well as using differnent Data Source configurations in the OleDbConnection.  This is shortened version of my connection:

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable(Name1, Address) VALUES(@FirstName, @Address)";
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\TEMP\\TestDatabase.accdb");
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtName.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Use full [UNC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192689/en-us) path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike's comment above re: UNC paths makes good sense. Just use

```
Data Source=\\servername\sharename\path\to\data\file.accdb;
```

Comment: I tried it that way(with double backslash between each) and it gives me the error 'C:\servername\sharename\path\database is not a valid path.'.  I don't get why it's still looking at the c drive.

Comment: If you need to double-up backslashes then you'll need 4 of them at the beginning to create the double-backslash that denotes the start of a UNC path. Or, you could use a `@"string literal"` and just use the normal number of backslashes. In other words, `"\\\\servername\\sharename\..."`, or `@"\\servername\sharename\..."`.